# If you can 50 pusbups in a go, why not make it harder by slowing down the tempo?

Tags: muscle, strength

As titled. Why do people say pushups are useless for muscle growth if you can do them in high rep?

Why not just slow down the tempo and making it hard enough that you can do only 10 reps? Why is this not an effective (and safer) strategy for muscle growth?

Answer (score 7):

There is a [meta-analysis](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40279-015-0304-0) by Schoenfeld that discusses the effect on hypertrophy when alterating repetition duration. They found that hypertrophy is similar when training with repetition durations ranging from 0.5 to 8 seconds, as long as sets were performed close to failure. They also found that training with a repetition duration greater than 10 seconds is likely inferior for hypertrophy.

Thus, slowing down your repetitions or even adding pauses can be used to progressive overload your bodyweight exercises.

On the other hand I need to adress that in all of the studies discussed by the Shoenfeld meta-analysis both the slow rep and the fast rep groups never worked outside what most people would consider the 'hypertrophy range'. The fast groups generally never went over 30 reps in a set.

Therefore, to directly adress your question: It is certainly questionable whether slowing down your rep tempo for an exercise you can do 50 repetitions of is an effective way of progressive overloading. If you would do the repetitions so slow that you can only do 10 reps as you write in your question, then the repetition duration would certainly be beyond 10 seconds, which is likely inferior as pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

You need to progressively overload a muscle for stimulate growth as your body  adapts to the movement. Once you slow down enough, you'll be performing (essentially) a static hold. How do you progress from there? Longer times will increase your endurance but not so much muscle growth.

Slowing down works for a while but at some point you need to increase the resistance with more weight. [This answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/how-is-hypertrophy-muscle-gain-provoked/31276#31276) has extra information about stimulating hypertrophy on a muscle.

Comment: FWIW, outside of stopping the movement entirely, slow push-ups aren't really static, although I guess you could see it as a continuum of static holds in a sort of Xeno's exercise plan. :-P That said, common practice for bodyweight adherents is to increase the effort, whether through more difficult pushups (elevated, diamond, wide, etc) or just adding weight via a backpack or accommodating child or pet.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is that "using a resistance so light that you could do a very large number of reps is suboptimal for hypertrophy", not that "doing high numbers of reps is suboptimal for hypertrophy".

If you can do 100 pushups, slowing them down to the point where you can only do 10 doesn't change anything. It's still a resistance so light that you could do 100 (normal speed) pushups, so it's still suboptimal for hypertrophy.

Or, looking at it differently, you could say that a set that takes you more than, say, 2 minutes to fatigue is suboptimal for hypertrophy. Doing 100 normal speed pushups in 3 minutes is then no different from doing 10 tempo pushups where each rep takes 18 seconds, for a total set time of 3 minutes.

You need more resistance, and tempo work does not provide that.

Comment: Why doesn't resistance increase with tempo?

Comment: @nz_21 Because your body mass and the force of gravity are independent of tempo.

Comment: @nz_21 the resistance is the amount of weight you're moving, not how difficult the movement feels. Tempo is lifting the same resistance more slowly.

Comment: you'll find a lot of disagreement there. Your muscles don't know the weight number you're lifting. If the goal is to cause muscle tears, why does the weight matter here?

Comment: @nz_21 The primary driver for hypertrophy is mechanical tension, not 'muscle tears'. Extremely oversimplified this means you want to fatigue your muscles. When working with very light loads the sets take so long that it is your central nervous system that will fatigue and force you to abandon the set before your muscles do.

Comment: @nz_21 Your muscles absolutely do know the weight number you're lifting (or, more precisely, how much muscular tension is needed to overcome it). It's called 'mechanotransduction'. More weight increases tension on the muscle. Slower tempo doesn't.

Comment: @leon.fuchsler what is a sign that your central nervous system has fatigured before the muscle has been torn?

Comment: @nz_21 central fatigue is defined as a reduction in your ability to voluntarily activate a muscle. There is no easy way to tell when this occurs. [Here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17697026/) is a study that compares the extent of central fatigue when using different loads.

Comment: If there's no easy  way, how can you be sure that doing 10 slow pushups is  worse than doing bench press?

I see that you've linked studies, but IMO they're about as trustworthy as the next gymbro. We're just assuming all participants in the study actually worked out with the right form, right intensity, right diet.  The "study" can be easily invalidated if you any of these variables were off.

Comment: If to you studies and scientific research are on par with the opinion of your average gymbro  then I am not sure why you asked your question on a site that generally expects answers to be research based. Just go ask a gymbro.

Comment: I'm asking here because if many gymbros  (dis)agreed, it's probably true. I appreciate the studies, thank you for linking them. I'm just not sure  I would trust them as much, given that there are so many variables at play. You can't take 10 random guy off the street for your research, have them do a leg press, and conclude that leg press is an effective exercise. It may only be effective if they've never worked out. There are so many other variables like this that make the studies redundant. I would argue that the average group of gymbros probably have *less* variance overall.